# Pyspark dataframe join based on key,group by and max

Tags: python, join, pyspark

i have two parquet files, which i load with spark.read. These 2 dataframes have a same column named key, so i join them with:

```
df = df.join(df2, on=['key'], how='inner')
```

df columns are: `["key","Duration","Distance"]` and df2 : `["key",department id"]`. At the end i want to print Duration, max(Distance),department id group by department id. What i have done so far is:

```
df.join(df.groupBy('departmentid').agg(F.max('Distance').alias('Distance')),on='Distance',how='leftsemi').show()
```

but i think it is too slow, is there a faster way to achieve my goal?
thanks in advance

EDIT: sample (first 2 lines of each file)
df:

```
369367789289,2015-03-27 18:29:39,2015-03-27 19:08:28,-
73.975051879882813,40.760562896728516,-
73.847900390625,40.732685089111328,34.8
369367789290,2015-03-27 18:29:40,2015-03-27 18:38:35,-
73.988876342773438,40.77423095703125,-
73.985160827636719,40.763439178466797,11.16
```

df1:

```
369367789289,1
369367789290,2
```

each columns is seperated by "," first column on both files is my key, then i have timestamps,longtitudes and latitudes. At the second file i have only the key and department id.
to create Distance i am using a function called formater. this is how i get my distance and duration:

```
df = df.filter("_c3!=0 and _c4!=0 and _c5!=0 and _c6!=0")
df = df.withColumn("_c0", df["_c0"].cast(LongType()))
df = df.withColumn("_c1", df["_c1"].cast(TimestampType()))
df = df.withColumn("_c2", df["_c2"].cast(TimestampType()))
df = df.withColumn("_c3", df["_c3"].cast(DoubleType()))
df = df.withColumn("_c4", df["_c4"].cast(DoubleType()))
df = df.withColumn("_c5", df["_c5"].cast(DoubleType()))
df = df.withColumn("_c6", df["_c6"].cast(DoubleType()))
df = df.withColumn('Distance', formater(df._c3,df._c5,df._c4,df._c6))
df = df.withColumn('Duration', F.unix_timestamp(df._c2) -F.unix_timestamp(df._c1))
```

and then as i showed above:

```
df = df.join(vendors, on=['key'], how='inner')
df.registerTempTable("taxi")
df.join(df.groupBy('vendor').agg(F.max('Distance').alias('Distance')),on='Distance',how='leftsemi').show()
```

Output must be

```
Distance    Duration    department id
```

grouped by id, and geting only the row with max(distance)

Comment: I think your code is slow because of this line `df.join(df.groupBy('departmentid').agg(F.max('Distance').alias('Distance')),on='Distance',how='leftsemi').show()' can you post some sample data and expected output. I think your task can be solved with a simple aggregation

Comment: ok i edited my post to show you